# Responsive website for desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I'm starting designing webpage, but still I don't understand so well about the media queries. I'm so confuse to do this. Is there any webpage that explain steps by steps about how to use this in CSS or if you can help me I will appreciate. I need to do this web page responsive for desktop and mobile.

So I need to create a div called "content" that is centered and has maximum 900px desktop width and will occupy 100% for mobile.

I need to uses medium queries to handle two sizes Desktop: with width of 900px or more and mobile with less than 900px. (Images must be responsive.)

Answer (score 1):

Media queries are like `logical` statements.

## If

"If" these things are true about the browser, use the CSS inside.

So you could have something like,
[image]

> You could read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/).

When using Responsive Grids, you can use,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with media queries and you need to do fast prototyping, my suggestion is to use bootstrap. Bootstrap will render accordingly for different devices .

You can easily plug bootstrap files and start developing : See the link on how to use bootstrap with examples : http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/

If you want to go with Css media queries , this will give you step by step implementation : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can browse through Youtube as there are ample amount of tutorials which shows how to develop a responsive website.You can start by looking into this : [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

In the tutorial from W3Schools, it will provide you required information to start with, which then you build up.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use bootstrap for responsive as per your device use grid system.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-
4</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) container fluid.

Or, try [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com). Hope these frameworks help you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to start with responsive is to use below code in head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Code for your web page:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Web Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .content{
    width: auto;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    ABC
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For responsive images use:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Hope it helps.